# Best Practices: EfCore/Linq - Single vs SingleOrDefault - Better exception messages

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I expect on item to be returned, but it could happen that the table is empty.

```
await context.Items
      .Where(x => x.Id == id)
      .SingleAsync()
```

The exception/exception message is not really useful.
"Source sequence doesn't contain any elements."

I could do something like ...

```
var singleOrDefault = await context.Items
      .Where(x => x.Id == id)
      .SingleOrDefault();

if(singleOrDefault == null)
   throw new Exception("No element in the table 'Items' found with the id '{id}'.")

return singleOrDefault;
```

I don't like this solution.
Too much unnecessary code for a case that will probably never occur in a production environment.

GOAL:
Is there a better way to get a useful exception?
Maybe by using single() or some extension?

Comment: _"but it could happen that the table is empty"_ vs _"for a case that will never happen"_ You contradict yourself here. This looks like normal defensive coding I would expect to see. Or you could return the null value and deal with it later.

Comment: It would be quite trivial to write a `SingleAsyncOrError(string message)` and/or `SingleAsyncOrError(Func<Exception> errorFactory)` extension method. Much less trivial, though still possible, would be an extension method that can generate the error message from the query context without a message parameter, but it would have to be made specific to EF. In fact if such a thing could be written I'm not sure it wouldn't make for a nice enhancement of EF itself.

Comment: You can't write your own extension methods as your linq provider (EF) has to be able to understand and generate code for anything in your linq expression

Comment: The error *is* useful. You didn't ask for the first result (FirstOrDefault), you asked for verification that there is only one result. A better option is to use `Items.FindAsync(id)` which also checks EF Core's cache and retrieves the object if it was already loaded. Besides, exceptions aren't user messages. If you want to display a specific user message, you'll have to actually write that code.

Comment: For example in a web app the correct message would be a 404 response, ie `Not Found`. So the real answer here is `Don't do it that way`

Comment: Either the error is really exceptional - in which case an exception should be generated with a meaningfull message - or it is completely valid program-flow- 
 in which case you shouldn't even think about any exception-message but avoid the case in the first place. From what you described it seems it's pretty common that the data is missing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to get a useful exception? Maybe by using single() or some extension? Is there nuget package for what i want?

Not really, at least none that I've found, as Jeroen said in the comments, this probably wouldn't be nice. Might be worth taking a look at a course on defensive coding.

The exception is quite self explanatory to you as the developer, "list is missing item you want", but not something you'd want to show to the user.

```
if(singleOrDefault == null)
   throw new Exception("No element in the table 'Items' found with the id '{id}'.")
```

This here is quite a common pattern, except you wouldn't throw an exception, you'd instead maybe return a null at which point you're logic would pick it up and return the issue to the user. (a 404 being the response code for http is probably the simplest way to illustrate this).

```
if(singleOrDefault == null)
  return null

...

var result = getItem(id)
if (result == null) {
  // Send error message to user
  NotFound("Could not find the item you are looking for");
} 

return result;
```

I would recommend against throwing an exception in this scenario as it's not unheard of that a resource gets deleted by one user while another tries to call it, or people store ids in text files and then try to reference them from a system.